# vbscript to save attachment from Outlook only saves 2 emails

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook

I have this script to auto save attachments from outlook in a folder but it only saves attachments from 2 emails at a time. How do I increase this to 3 or 4?

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objMailbox = objNamespace.Folders("Mailbox - ABC")
Set objFolder = objMailbox.Folders("Inbox")

Set colItems = objFolder.Items
Set colFilteredItems = colItems.Restrict("[UnRead] = True")

For Each objMessage in colFilteredItems
    intCount = objMessage.Attachments.Count
    If intCount > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To intCount
            objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile "C:\" &  _
                objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).FileName
        Next 
    End If
    objMessage.Unread = False
Next
```

Comment: `Item(i).FileName` might be empty or invalid. You could try `Item(i).DisplayName` or create an artificial name like `"att" & i & ".dat"`. Log the names using `Debug.print`. It is not recommended to write files directly into "C:\". You could spoil your system. Take another directory where you have adequate access rights. Check the `Attachment.Type` property and skip embedded Attachments (olEmbeddedItem = 5). They cannot be saved as files.

Comment: @Axel Thanks I will try displayname  and skip embeddeditem and see if it works

Comment: @Axel - Doesn't work. The issue seems to be that it doesn't check more than 2 emails. Once it looks at the email it is downloading all attachments. So if I have 3 unread emails with attachments, it only reads 2 emails and leaves the third.

Comment: If you are looping through a folder, there might be item objects which are no MailItems. Use `if objMessage.Class = olMail then ...` to avoid errors.

Comment: This code looks solid, possibly either the saveasfile command takes to long to process or your error handling doesn't indicate anything. Maybe add an "if err.number <> 0 then msgbox err.description" after your "SaveAsFile" command?

Comment: @Rich - Thanks I figured out that it was the restrict "Unread". I changed the condition to restrict by sender email and added an if condition for "unread" and now it works!!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, works for the emails in the main Inbox:

```
Set outlook = createobject("outlook.application")
Set session = outlook.getnamespace("mapi")
session.logon

Set inbox = session.getdefaultfolder(6) // inbox is 6

For Each m In inbox.items
  If m.unread  Then 
    intCount = m.Attachments.Count
    If intCount > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To intCount
            m.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile "C:\pic\" &  _
                m.Attachments.Item(i).FileName
        Next 
    End If
    m.Unread = False
  End If
Next

session.logoff

Set outlook = Nothing
Set CaseTitle = Nothing
Set session = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

If you want to get attachments of a folder inside the inbox, then simply place the following line:

```
Set inbox = session.getdefaultfolder(6).Folders("FolderName")
```

Comment: Do not loop through all items in a folder - there can be tens of thousands of them.

Comment: At the beginning, the user has to "mark as unread" all the relevant emails which contain the attachments. In that way, no unnecessary emails will be considered. And I have practically tried this code for thousands of them. It won't crash if the user marks the relevant emails as unread ones.

Comment: Turn cached mode off and run your script against a folder with a few thousand emails. Once gain, don't do that. That is what Items.Restrict and Items.Find/FindNext are for.

Answer (score 0):

Commenting this with changes which is working fine to download all attachments

```
Const olFolderInbox = 6

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objMailbox = objNamespace.Folders("Mailbox - ABC")
Set objFolder = objMailbox.Folders("Inbox")

Set colItems = objFolder.Items
Set colFilteredItems = colItems.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'test@gmail.com'")

For Each objMessage in colFilteredItems
    intCount = objMessage.Attachments.Count
    If intCount > 0 Then
        For i = 1 To intCount
            objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile "C:\" &  _
                objMessage.Attachments.Item(i).FileName
        Next 
    End If
    objMessage.Unread = False
Next
```

Comment: Why does this work? Please add an explanation.